# About Event Listen of Kinetic JS

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Below is the code. My expectation is when I hover on the circles, they should show "Circle 0" and "Circle 1" respectively. But they all show "Circle 1".

Why is this and How to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
      function writeMessage(message) {
        text.setText(message);
        layer.draw();
      }
      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 200
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fontSize: 24,
        text: '',
        fill: 'black'
      });

      for (var n=0; n<2; ++n)
      {
          var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 100 + n * 100,
            y: stage.height()/2,
            radius: 30,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4
          });
          var txt = 'Circle ' + n;
          circle.on('mouseover', function() {
            writeMessage(txt);
          });
          circle.on('mouseout', function() {
            writeMessage('');
          });
          layer.add(circle);
      }

      layer.add(text);
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with Kinetic, it's related to JavaScript closures.

You're defining a function in a loop here:

```
for (var n=0; n<2; ++n) {
  ...
  var txt = 'Circle ' + n;
  circle.on('mouseover', function() {
    writeMessage(txt);
  });
  ...
}
```

The variable `txt` is not copied when you declare your function.
The problem is that when your anonymous function gets called, the value of `txt` is `'Circle 1'` (because the `for` has finished and `txt` was modified during the loop).

You'll need an intermediate function:

```
var displayMessage = function (circleNumber) {
  var txt = 'Circle ' + circleNumber;
  return function () {
    writeMessage(txt);
  };
};
```

and your event binding is now :

```
circle.on('mouseover', displayMessage(n));
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GApn7/

If you want to read more on what happens, read this post: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)